# Solving partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I wonder if anyone could solve the equation below (analytically) for $p(x,t)$?

$$\dfrac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial (u(x) p(x,t))}{\partial x}$$

The conditions are as follows:

\begin{align}
u(x) &= \cos \bigg( \frac{2 \pi x}{l} \bigg) + \frac{d}{2} \cos \bigg( \frac{4 \pi x}{l} \bigg) \\
p(x,0) &= \delta(x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial (u(x) p(x,t))}{\partial x} \quad\to\quad \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial t}-u\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}= u'p \quad\text{where}\quad u'=\frac{du}{dx}$$
Solving thanks to the method of characteristics :

System of characteristic differential equations $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-u}=\frac{dp}{u'p}$

First characteristic curve, from $\frac{u'dx}{u}+\frac{dp}{p}=0\quad\to\quad up=c_1$

Second characteristic curve, from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-u} \quad\to\quad t+\int\frac{dx}{u}=c_2$

General solution on the form of implicit equation $\Phi\left(c_1\:,\:c_2\right)=0$ where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables :
$$\Phi\left(up\:,\:t+\int\frac{dx}{u}\right)=0$$
An equivalent form of any relationship between the two variable is the explicit equation $\quad up=F\left(t+\int\frac{dx}{u}\right)$ where $F$ is any differentiable function.
$$p(x,t)=\frac{1}{u(x)}F\left(t+\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}\right)$$

At this step, since the wording of the question was changed, the answer also is changed :

Suppose that the initial condition be :
$$p(x,0)=g(x)\qquad\text{with }g(x)\text{ a given function}.$$
One have to determine the function $F$ which satisfies the equation :
$\frac{1}{u(x)}F\left(\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}\right)=g(x)$
$$F\left(\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}\right)=g(x)u(x)$$
Let $X(x)=\int\frac{dx}{u(x)} \qquad\to\qquad x=$inverse function of $\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}=G(X)$

Since $u(x)$ is a given function, $G(X)$ is given. This doesn't mean that $G(X)$ is known on a closed form. This is not the case if the antiderivative of $\frac{dx}{u(x)}$ is not known on a closed form. Moreover, a closed form might not be known for the inverse function.

$$F(X)=g\left(G(X)\right)u\left(G(X)\right)$$

On a pure formal form, the solution of the problem is :
$$p(x,t)=\frac{1}{u(x)}g\left(G\left(t+\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}\right)\right)u\left(G\left(t+\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}\right)\right)$$
where $g$ , $u$ , $G$ , are functions given or derived from given functions.
As already pointed out, this doesn't mean that one can express all of them on closed form.

For example, in case of $p(x,0)=\delta(x) \quad\to\quad g(x)=\delta(x)$. But we also need to express $G(x)$ which involves the inverse function of $\int \frac{dx}{\cos \bigg( \frac{2 \pi x}{l} \bigg) + \frac{d}{2} \cos \bigg( \frac{4 \pi x}{l} \bigg)}$.

The main difficulty comes more from the kind of function $u(x)$ specified than from the initial condition.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. two questions:1- do you mean there is no  Do you mean this method can't give any analytic answer  with the condition of integral or you mean there is not any solution for this equation in general? 2_ what if one ignores about the integral condition? How can F be determined? @JJacquelin

Comment: For ex. substituting integral condition with p(x,0)= delta(x)

Comment: I don't say that  there is not any solution for this equation. I say that with this kind of function $u(x)$ in $\int \frac{dx}{u(x)}$ without closed form for this integral and even worse without closed form for the inverse function of this integral, it is doubtful that a closed form made of standard functions can be derived in the GENERAL case of initial condition.

Comment: What about initial condition: p(x,0)= \delta (x) @JJacquelin

Comment: With this initial condition, you have to solve $F\left(\int \frac{dx}{u(x)}\right)=\delta(x)$ for $F$. Good luck !.

Comment: I know, but it cannot be solved! @JJacquelin

Comment: That was what I said. But this doesn't mean that no solution exists. That means that we cannot find  a closed for made of standard functions with this initial condition. It is common to encounter problems which have a solution which cannot be expressed with the standard function that we know at present time.

Comment: Is there any initial condition which the equation could be solved analytically with? @JJacquelin